# layering PDFs together and have ability to set the position

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I'm being tasked to enhance the way we create custom brochures, the  old way we had a legacy system create the needed pdfs and then I would download those and "glue" them into one big pdf.

the new one way we want to go about this is to skip the legacy system and build all of these things from our new system.

The biggest hurdle is the cover, which consists of the background layer, and then the logo layer which has the company logo, a shadowbox and an emblem. all of these objects are pdf documents.

my problem is after I build the logo portion, how will I be able to position the pdf exactly where I need it on the background layer?

this is all being done on the fly so I can't save anything to disk.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several PDFsharp samples that show how to do it:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/XForms-sample.ashx
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Draw_a_form_XObject_a_page_from_an_external_PDF_file_27
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/TwoPagesOnOne-sample.ashx

You can draw pages from other PDF files like images on a newly created PDF page. You can specify the exact positions and sizes, you can even transform them (skew them, rotate them).

Comment: This did help me, thanks. I'm still hitting the wall however on getting the logo pdf to attach to the cover pdf. I may have to temporary save that pdf, but I'd rather not.

Comment: I saved the logo as a byte array and now everything is working smoothly.